# Query in WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND clause. Bad practice?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Developers at our job are constantly using the follow construct:

```
BEGIN    
  SELECT field1 
  INTO l_field1
  FROM table1
  WHERE field2 = 'some value'
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  THEN
     SELECT field2 
     INTO l_field2
     FROM table2
     WHERE field3 = 'some value'
   ...
END;
```

What basically means - if you don't find the record in the first table then go look in the second table.

I have a strong feeling that this is wrong and is a bad lazy practice. But how would you approach it? Would you first get the COUNT in the table1 and if number of rows is zero then go and look in table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are asking for an alternative way, you can use the below way. When No data found is considered to handle errors or warning, , not conditions. Exceptions helps you to handle errors , if you were trying to run several selects and you had an error .the exception will help you detect you check the below example.

```
BEGIN   
declare cnt number(4); 
select count(1) into cnt from table1 where field2 = 'some value';
if cnt >0 then
  SELECT field1 
  INTO l_field1
  FROM table1
  WHERE field2 = 'some value'
else if cnt =0 then
  SELECT field2 
     INTO l_field2
     FROM table2
     WHERE field3 = 'some value';
end if;
   END;
```

With exceptions, you can handle errors conveniently without the need to code multiple checks, as follows:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT ...
   SELECT ...
   SELECT ...
   ...
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  -- catches all 'no data found' errors
```

for more information about exception and handling errors check [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm)

Comment: Thanks Moudiz. That makes sense with count(*). As far as multiple SELECT statements in the same block, how would you know which statement errored out? I always thought it is better to have a separate block for each select statement.

Comment: @Roman the above was an example provided from the documentation, a begin with multiple select.anywya it is always depends on what you need.

Comment: The very fact that you need to do this strongly suggests that you are starting with a flawed data model that has not been properly designed to Third Normal Form.

Comment: @EdStevens sorry i didnt understand you can you explain please

Comment: @Moudiz - The full explanation is too involved for this format, Ask yourself why you have to look in a second table for data if it's not in the first.  Review the rules for Data Normalization.

Comment: @EdStevens ah okay now i understand you, the below was an alternative example of the way he mentioned in his answer, I dont know what is he doing.. however I use this way as checking sometimes I run some DML several time so I add this as count(1) checking so I dont get error such unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

My objection to the "SELECT-in-an-EXCEPTION" stuff is that it nests blocks which have no business being nested. My preference is to use a boolean indicator variable, similar to the following:

```
DECLARE
  bNot_found  BOOLEAN := FALSE;
  l_field1    TABLE1.FIELD1%TYPE;
  l_field2    TABLE2.FIELD2%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN    
    SELECT field1 
      INTO l_field1
      FROM table1
      WHERE field2 = 'some value';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      bNot_found := TRUE;
  END;

  IF bNot_found THEN
   SELECT field2 
     INTO l_field2
     FROM table2
     WHERE field3 = 'some value';
  END IF;

  -- Go thou and do good works

END;
```